# Need to break down into day..Right now its rolled up into months

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  A.SPLIT, 

     SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CH,
     SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN abandon_time IS NOT NULL  AND answer_time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CO,
SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 1 END) AS AHT 
FROM    reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  A.CALENDAR_DATE >= '10/01/2015' AND A.CALENDAR_DATE <= '9/30/2016' AND A.SPLIT IN (9,26,23,43,48,33,56,70,71,72,74,50) AND ( A.ent_split IS NOT NULL)
Group BY A.SPLIT
```

Heres is some of the data my code puts out.

```
              Split     CH      CO      AHT
                9     957157 1156319  1156461
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Right the information in CH, CO, and AHT  the data reflects everything from 10/1/2015 to 9/30/2016. I would like for the data to show each day like 10/1/2015, 10/2/2015 and so on.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
SELECT  A.SPLIT, A.CALENDAR_DATE,
     SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CH,
     SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN abandon_time IS NOT NULL  AND answer_time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CO,
SUM(CASE WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%' THEN 1 ELSE 1 END) AS AHT 
FROM    reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  A.CALENDAR_DATE >= '10/01/2015' AND A.CALENDAR_DATE <= '9/30/2016' AND A.SPLIT IN (9,26,23,43,48,33,56,70,71,72,74,50) AND ( A.ent_split IS NOT NULL)
Group BY A.SPLIT, A.CALENDAR_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed.. I couldn't get it to work for the life of me keep getting error out.